# What email app can filter mail by size?

Tags: applications, email

I'm looking for an Android email client (preferably free) for my Galaxy S4 that has the feature of filtering incoming email by size, that is: some kind of rule of the type: if email is more than [insert number] Kb, don't download from server, etc.

An alternative would be to filter incoming mail with attachments, as all I really want is to not download big emails.

I have tried some popular apps including the default Samsung app, CloudMagic, Mailbox and all seem to lack this apparently basic funcionality.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure if it has it, but [K-9 Mail](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fsck.k9) has a lot of settings, so it might be worth a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[K-9 Mail app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fsck.k9&hl=en) (available on PlayStore) will filter by attachments, plus several other choices. It is [open sourced](https://code.google.com/p/k9mail/) and free.

Comment: I just added the links to your post, otherwise unchanged.

Comment: K9 did the trick, it filters by size too, and it comes with that option enabled by default!! (Fetch messages up to 32Kb).

Comment: @RossC thanks, my connection was really bad, also had issues editing....fixed now

Answer (score 0):

Try this email app, it works very good with [hotmail and outlook account](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.syntomo.email&hl=en)